# urllib2.urlopen is raising UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, urllib2

This part of the scraper works well with some URLs, but when it comes to sites from Brasil for example, it raises an exception error **UnicodeEncodeError**.

```
hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(webpage,headers=hdr)
print type(req) # Instance
fetched_url = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout = 5)
```

the type of **req** is "instance", should I encode it otherwise like utf-8 for example and how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Exactly which line throws the exception?

Comment: fetched_url = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout = 5) exactly this line.

Answer (score 0):

URLs can include Unicode characters.
See [this page from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#utility-functions), for some utility functions for handling those. The percentage-encoding is probably the safest way, but not so easy to handle.

**Edit:**
Lol this actually got interesting. The most straightforward and productive way would be to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) package. It is even linked to in the official python docs.